# Stop OpenLayers featureselected event listener blocking map drag event

Tags: openlayers-2

When trying to drag the map, if the user clicks on a vector feature the `featureselected` event is triggered and the map dragging does not happen. Please try to drag the map starting from any feature in the example below.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html

Is it possible to disable the `featureselected` event so the map can be dragged?

**Solution**

i found this FAQ http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/SelectFeatureControlMapDragIssues

It works.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying you want to drag a feature, or drag the map regardless of whether a feature or the map is clicked on?

Comment: i want to drag the map.

Comment: Do you need the selectFeature control? if not, you can remove it from the map or deactivate it.

Comment: A sample without selectFeature implementation is visible here : http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/behavior-fixed-http-gml.html

Comment: i need the selectfeature control too.

Comment: what was solution ? as there is nothing showing now can you provide solution I need it

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119540)

Comment: @OtoKaláb I already ask before 5 hours still not even comment. somehow this question maybe matches my question . And I dont have enogh repu to comment so I have to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided specifically demonstrates the ability to select features from different layers. In order to do this it includes an `OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature` that is setup to capture `featureselected` events on the two different vector layers. Removing (or deactivating) the `OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature` control will revert to default behaviour, that is to say the feature does not capture the mouse event and instead the map does, allowing it to be dragged.

The example given by simo does not include the `OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature` control and therefore demonstrates the map can dragged regardless of whether a feature or the underlying map is clicked on.

If you need the ability to select the feature as well as being able to drag the map when a feature is initially clicked then you will need to look at extending the event so that `fallThrough` is set to `true` - which allows the event to fall through after it has been handled. This might then allow the map to pick up the click and drag event. I've not tried that so don't know if it would work.

Comment: i try set map.fallThrough = true; but seem like not working.

Comment: map.fallThrough is different. You need to extend the featureselected event to set fallThrough to true. Then when your code to handle the featureselected event has completed the vent should fall through to the map.